# TIdStream undeclared Using Indy library IdHttp.Request.Post(string, TIdStream) . IdObjs and IdBaseObjs namespaces not recognised

Tags: delphi, indy

There is a list of the overloaded Post methods at:

http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=%21%21OVERLOADED_Post_TIdCustomHTTP.html

The IDE is rejecting a declaration of a variable of type TIdStream:

```
    function TVClientCall<T, I>.ExecuteCall(pURL: string; pDataParams: string): string;
var
  vRequestStream: TStringStream;
  vTIDRequestStream: TIdStream;
```

.
.

The Indy docs place it in the IdObjs.pas library, which does not seem to exist in XE6?

Is IdObjs a sub-namespace of one of the other libraries? If so - which one? Is TIdStream abstract and if so which subclass type am I meant to use?

Comment: You have the source, don't you? You can see for yourself where the class is declared.

Comment: He was not being rude. By using notepad++ or another tool you will be able to find, in the source tree, where the class is declared. (E.g. Delphi IDE -> Ctrl+F -> Find in Files). You must put the unit in the interface's uses section, though.

Answer (score 4):

`TIdStream` isn't declared anywhere anymore. It's also not used. The declaration of `TIdCustomHTTP.Post` now uses plain old `TStream`:

```
procedure Post(AURL: string; ASource, AResponseContent: TStream); overload;
```

I'm referring to the [latest development snapshot](http://indy.fulgan.com/ZIP/) (5161). The online documentation evidently hasn't been updated to reflect the new stream policy.

I learned this by doing a regex search of the source code for `TIdStream\s*=`. Finding nothing, I then went to the `TIdCustomHTTP` declaration in *IdHTTP.pas*.

`TStream` is abstract; you mustn't instantiate it directly. Use whichever descendant class fits your needs. Common options include `TFileStream`, `TMemoryStream`, and `TStringStream`.

Comment: Indy's documentation has not been updated in a LONG time (work on that is in progress but slow).  The `IdSys` and `IdObj` units were phased out of Indy years ago, and the `TIdStream` class no longer exists (there is an `IdStream.pas` unit, but you should not use it directly. It defines a `TIdStreamHelper` class for reading/writing data in Delphi's and .NET's different Stream classes, but the `IdGlobal.pas` unit has public wrappers for `TIdStreamHelper` that should be used instead).